# Pushing file to get that exceeds file size, but after cleaning up the file and reducing the file size

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook

I have a github repo with a few jupyter notebooks for doing some data cleanup with a large file. I accidentally pushed a notebook to github that had a large output cell which increased the size of the file immensely. After getting an error about the file size, I cleaned up the output of the jupyter notebook, which reduced the file size to 28kb. Now when I try to push that file to github, I get the following error about the file size:

```
    MacBook-Air:$ git push
    Enter passphrase for key '/Users/.ssh/id_rsa': 
    Counting objects: 9, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 6.17 MiB | 99.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 9 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), completed with 1 local object.
    remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
    remote: error: Trace: 7124124eb1e187e4668cbf0f75634827
    remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
    remote: error: File Data_cleanup.ipynb is 116.86 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
    To github.com:jeff326/Data_Tools_Brazil_Weather.git
     ! [remote rejected] First_exploration_SR -> First_exploration_SR (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:****/***Brazil_Weather.git'
```

What is the best way to clean up this follow up issue? Much appreciation for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history